# How to set validation notification text programatically to textbox in silverlight? 

Tags: silverlight, validation

I want to set validation notification message to a text box control. I want to set it on **BindingValidationError** event of the TextBox.

What property of textbox control will set the validation message.

[I want to set Message like The Name field required](http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/fredriknormen/image_16774D87.png)

Answer (score 0):

In xaml,

Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="97,2,0,2" >

in xaml.cs,

public MyViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return (MyViewModel)this.DataContext;
            }
            set
            {
                this.DataContext = value;
            }
        }

in 
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

private string _name = "kanal";
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Name is required");
                }
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler pceh = PropertyChanged;
            if (pceh != null)
            {
                pceh(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
}

Comment: Thomas I dont want do it through MVVM . i want in code behind